# Could not compile UIFont category

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a very simple UIFont category:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIFont (MyCategory)
- (CGFloat)test;
@end
```

And I got compiler errors:

```
Missing @end
Method type specifier must start with '-' or '+'
```

I created another UIFont category, and the compiler is ok with it.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIFont (Test)
- (CGFloat)test;
@end
```

Is it a bug in xcode?

Answer (score 3):

The possibility that this is a bug in Xcode is *very* unlikely.

A better chance is an invisible character in your code.  Try deleting it and re-typing.

Answer (score 1):

I've written your exact code and that compiles fine, even without any implementation file.

There is a good chance that you have an invisible character somewhere in the first try. Check also if your file's name is not problematic (low chance, but why not).

What happens if you get the working version and replace Test by MyCategory ?

Comment: I created a new project and copy the exact same files to the new project. Everything is compiled fine.

Comment: @user1036167 : that's strange... ?? :-)  Well, if that works... Hope my answer could help you a little bit :-)

Comment: It turned out it was caused by two things: 1) a previous import .h file missing @end 2) one of the .h missing necessary UIKit.h. Xcode should have complained about the original errors, instead, it errors the files which are correct.

Comment: @user1036167 : Thank you for that return. I hope I could help a little bit :-)